# Java array add new value to the first and remove the last

Tags: java, arrays, push

I'm trying to update my array so if you add something to the first array tail[0] The whole array updates and moves 1 to the next and at the end the last one tail[49] gets removed.

So if I add a value to tail[0] I want tail[1] to get the old tail[0] value, tail[2] to get the old tail[1] value and tail[3] to get the old tail[2] value. the value of the old tail[3] will get removed. This is like a array push where you remove the last value each time.

I tried this so far but I can't manage to get it to work.

Create array:

```
Tail[] tail = new Tail[50];
```

Give the whole array a value:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tail.length; i++){
    tail[i] = new Tail(0,0);
}
```

Update the array so it adds a new value and removes the last value.

```
public void tail(){

    tail[0] = new Tail(ball.getX(),ball.getY());

    for(int i = 1; i < tail.length; i++){
        tail[i] = new Tail(tail[i-1].x,tail[i-1].x);
    }
}
```

Tail class:

```
public class Tail {

    public float x;
    public float y;

    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    public boolean active = false;

    public Tail(float x, float y){
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

          batch.begin();
          shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
          shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, 16);
          shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          shapeRenderer.end();
          batch.end();  

        Gdx.app.log("TailX"+x, "TailY"+y);
    }

}
```

The tail void ends up crashing my game whats the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just use a queue?

Comment: @MAV how do I exactly use a queue in java to create multiple objects?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question. But your initial description _" ..The whole array updates and moves 1 to the next and at the end the last one tail[49] gets removed."_ sounds like a place where a FIFO data structure (like a Queue) is useful. It would allow you to insert an element and then remove the last element, without having to move the position of all the other elements. 
In your code it seems like you're creating new `Tail` instances every time. Any reason for that?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to create like a tail just like the snake game where the tail keeps updating with new coordinates so it follows the head of the snake. But creating the Tail objects once is probally better?

Comment: post the implementation of `Tail` class please

Comment: @SagarD I added the tail class to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems like you're creating a new `Tail` when you attempt to move the tails. Any reason for that? You should be able to re-use the same instances, by just moving the reference.

Also, in your code you're trying to insert the new element at position 0, *before* moving all the other elements. You need to do it the other way around, to make sure only the last item is removed. Should be doable with something like this:

```
for(int i = tail.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
    tail[i + 1] = tail[i];
}
tail[0] = new Tail(ball.getX(),ball.getY());
```

This way you are just moving the `Tail` instances, rather than creating new ones. Unless I misunderstood something, this should work.

It does sound like you could benefit from using a Queue instead. A Queue is designed to insert elements in one end and retrieve items from the other end.

If you used a `LinkedList` (it implements the `Deque` interface) instead of an array, you should be able to do something like this:

```
tail.addFirst(new Tail(ball.getX(), ball.getY()));
tail.removeLast();
```

Comment: This is getting closer its drawing the circles but when the ball hits the wall the tail stays at the same side where it started. And is not following the ball anymore but infront of it

Comment: What do you mean it is not following the ball? Is the elements being moved correctly? Is the new `Tail` instance correct when the ball hits a wall?

Comment: At the beginning the tail follows correctly but as soon as the ball hits the wall the tail stays at the same side and doesnt move behind the ball its path

Comment: Hm. Sounds like there is more involved than just moving items in an array. I _think_ the problem lies elsewhere (in code you have not posted here), but I can't be sure.

Comment: Oh its working now for some reason but the full tail gets drawn at the same place so you can only see 1 ball following instead of 50

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the X and Y values. Make sure that the Tail instances have the correct values and make sure they are used when positioning on screen.

Comment: 40: TailX231.79996 41: TailX231.79996 all tails get the same x/y coordinates in the forloop for some reason it doesnt push the value to the next in the next in the array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69805/discussion-between-mav-and-stefan).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use arrays for something like this - use Stack instead.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more? How I should use this with my code?

Comment: How would a stack help him remove the last element after an insert?

Comment: @MAV - he can use pop() to remove that element.

Comment: But a Stack is a LIFO data structure, so popping an element should return the first item (i.e. the item you just inserted). Are you sure you do not mean a Queue?

Comment: you can handle a remove (first or last element) doing stack.remove(stack.lastElement())(is a pop operation) or stack.remove(stack.firstElement())

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code (Updated)

```
public void tail(){

    float tempx = ball.getX();
    float tempy = ball.getY()

    for(int i =(tail.length - 1); i > 0; i--){
        tail[i].x = tail[i-1].x;
        tail[i].y = tail[i-1].y;

    }
    tail[0].x = tempx;
    tail[0].y = tempy;
}
```

Comment: tail[i].x tail[i-1].x; ended up with an error so I added a = inbetween them. This ends up with a x and a y from 0 each time in the tail class.

Comment: the tempx/tempy updates but for some reason it doesnt reach the tail class if i log the x and y there they both stay 0 also in the tail void the tail[i] updates but it just doesnt reach the tail class for some reason

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is similar to **FIFO**  . So you can use Queue to implement this functionality .

[image]

```
Object firstElement = queue.remove();
```

To remove elements from a queue, you call the **remove()** method. This method removes the element at the head of the queue. In most Queue implementations the head and tail of the queue are at opposite ends

```
Queue queueA = new LinkedList();

queueA.add("element 0");
queueA.add("element 1");
queueA.add("element 2");
```

The **add()** method adds the element to the tail

Now if you call queueA.remove();

it will give the first element inserted which is

```
element 0
```

Now use this and implement your own logic .

Comment: Allright but how do you exactly get the new x and y coordinates so the tail class knows where to draw each frame?

Comment: I have given the answer in perspective to "Java array add new value to the first and remove the last" , but if you want to get x and y coordinates , then set them before entering them into queue , and at removal of the item just access those coordinates and draw the frame

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an array for it. Use something like a Stack that could work like the following:

```
Stack stack = new Stack();

//you add elements to stack using push method
stack.push("Test");
stack.push("Test2");
```

Comment: This ends up giving me the error push is undefined for the type tail? This is how I tried to use it: tail.push(ball.getX(),ball.getY());